# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable Python with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, concatenation

```
clips = []

def clipFinder(CurrentDir, fileType):
    clips.clear()
    for r,d,f in os.walk(CurrentDir):
        for file in f:
            if fileType in file:
                clips.append(r+file)
    random.shuffle(clips)

def removeVods(r):
    for f in clips:
        if 'vod' in clips:
            os.remove(r+f)

def clipString():
    string = 'intermediate'
    clipList = []
    clipNum = 1
    for f in clips:
        clipList.append(string+str(clipNum)+'.ts'+'|')
        clipNum+=1
    string1 = ''.join(clipList)
    string2 = string1[0:len(string1)-1]
    return string2

def concatFiles():
    clipFinder('***', '.mp4')
    removeVods('***')
    i = 0
    intermediates = []
    for f in clips:
        subprocess.call(['***', '-i', clips[i], '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:v', 'h264_mp4toannexb', '-f', 'mpegts', 'intermediate'+ str(i+1) +'.ts'])
        i += 1 
    clipsLength = len(clips)
    subprocess.call['***', '-i', '"concat:' + clipString() + '"', '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:a 
    aac_adtstoasc', 'output.mp4']
```

I am trying to make a clip concatenator, but the last subprocess call won't run and gives me the error shown in the question.

Problematic code:

```
subprocess.call(['***', '-i', '"concat:' + clipString() + '"', '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc', 'output.mp4'])
```

all places with * were paths such as:
/davidscomputer/bin/ffmpeg/

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.call()` is a callable by definition. You missed the brackets around it

`subprocess.call(['***', '-i', '"concat:' + clipString() + '"', '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc', 'output.mp4'])`

Comment: for some reason, even with the brackets, the code doesn't function properly

Comment: Can you print the list you are calling `subprocess.call` with?

Comment: yes. The command works fine when I run it in terminal. However, when I try running it using subprocess it does not work. The list doesn't feed directly into the command it is passed through the clip string function to generate a string that gets added into the command. I can also print that string and it looks fine.

Comment: @S1mple, I am sorry what I mean is the list going to `subprocess.call()`, if we join the list elements using spaces than the resulting string, if that directly run in the shell, works fine or not? If it errors out there than the problem lies somewhere in your code, else we would have to look up in the `subprocess` domain. Please add the corresponding command, along with the output in shell

Comment: The command runs fine in shell as a unix command. I was using this link to make my FFmpeg commands https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: If you scroll down to the section called "Using intermediate files" you can see the commands that i adapted into my code using subprocess