# Last subprocess call not working in concatenation code with FFMPEG. How should I go about fixing this?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

```
clips = []

#generates a list of mp4 files in a folder
def clipFinder(CurrentDir, fileType):
    clips.clear()
    for r,d,f in os.walk(CurrentDir):
        for file in f:
            if fileType in file:
                clips.append(r+file)
    random.shuffle(clips)

#removes all files that have the string 'vod' in them as they cause problems during concatenation
def removeVods(r):
    for f in clips:
        if 'vod' in clips:
            os.remove(r+f)

#generates a string using the clips list to insert into the ffmpeg command
def clipString():
    string = 'intermediate'
    clipList = []
    clipNum = 1
    for f in clips:
        clipList.append(string+str(clipNum)+'.ts'+'|')
        clipNum+=1
    string1 = ''.join(clipList)
    string2 = string1[0:len(string1)-1]
    return string2

#concatenates the mp4 files in the clipString
def concatFiles():
    clipFinder('***', '.mp4')
    removeVods('***')
    i = 0
    intermediates = []
    for f in clips:
        subprocess.call(['***', '-i', clips[i], '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:v', 'h264_mp4toannexb', '-f', 'mpegts', 'intermediate'+ str(i+1) +'.ts'])
        i += 1 
    clipsLength = len(clips)
    subprocess.call['***', '-i', '"concat:' + clipString() + '"', '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:a 
    aac_adtstoasc', 'output.mp4']
```

I am trying to make a clip concatenator, but the last subprocess call won't run and gives me no error. When I run the script the first FFmpeg call works fine and gives me my intermediate mp4 files, however, the second command, which works when I run it in terminal, does not work when I run it from python using subprocess.call.

Problematic code:

```
subprocess.call(['***', '-i', '"concat:' + clipString() + '"', '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc', 'output.mp4'])
```

all places with * were paths such as: /davidscomputer/bin/ffmpeg/

Comment: "gives me the error shown in the question." What is the error? I don't see it.

Comment: I added more to my description. Hopefully, it makes more sense now. I'm sure that I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable Python with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026080/typeerror-function-object-is-not-subscriptable-python-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: I don't know python, so I can't comment on the issue from that, but does the second ffmpeg command actually get executed? Anyway, you can skip the creation of the intermediate files. Just use the concat demuxer.

Comment: I like to keep the intermediates because it lends to an easier string generation for the second FFmpeg. I think that you are completely correct @llogan about the second command not executing, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem code:
    subprocess.call['***', '-i', '"concat:' + clipString() + '"', '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc', 'output.mp4']

Solution:
    commandString = ['/Users/teoscomputer/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', 'concat:' + clipString(), '-c', 'copy', '-bsf:a', 'aac_adtstoasc', 'output.mp4']
    subprocess.Popen(commandString)

There were two problems:
1) the, '-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc' needed to be separated into, '-bsf:a', 'aac_adtstoasc'

2)the " quotes around the concat needed to be removed as they are only needed when running a direct command in the shell